# use image along with text

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I am here with a very little and basic problem. I have an image and a lot of text. I want my image to occupy its space and then the remaining space should be filled with text, also the space on the right of the image. But, the text always started from the next line where the image ended. Heres the code.

```
<p style="float:left;">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Maria_Amalia.jpg" />
Princess Maria Amélia of Brazil (1831–1853) was the daughter of Dom Pedro I, founder of Brazil's independence and here continues my text...</p>
```

Jssfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xpncr/

Comment: There is a nice new `figure` tag in HTML5 along with its buddy, `figcaption`, that might be a little more appropriate here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to put `float: left` on your image.

```
<p>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Maria_Amalia.jpg" style="float: left;" />
    Princess Maria Amélia of Brazil (1831–1853) was the daughter of Dom Pedro I, founder of Brazil's independence and
</p>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xpncr/1/

Comment: @3dgoo +1 Vote for typing faster than me :D